# SQL: determine if even one 1:many is in another 1:many

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the shipping industry where there are companies that move stuff (carriers) and companies that ship stuff (shippers). Each has routes that they take based on states. For example a shipper sends things from Maine to California, Maine to Kansas, New Hampshire to Alabama, etc. Carriers, similarly have "routes" that they take again defined by state-to-state. I want to use a SQL query that quickly selects carriers for a shipper that have at least one match between ANY shiping origin/destination and any carrier route.

The database layout is as follows:

Shipper is a 1:m relationship to contracts. Contract has 1:m relationship to lanes. A lane is defined in its simplest term originState and destinationState.

From here I need to query all possible carriers to see which ones could possibly bid on that contract which equates to that the carrier has at least one route it supports that matches any one of the contracts lanes. Figure carrier table with a 1:m relationship to all of it's "routes", again defined as originState and destinationState.

At this point, I just need the list of carriers that match. I don't even care which route matches, just the fact that they are eligible to bid on the contract.

Thanks!

As requested, below is the current query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    r.id as contractId, c.id as carrierId
FROM
    contract r
        JOIN
    contractLane rl ON rl.contractId = r.id
        JOIN
    lane l on l.origState = rl.originState and l.destState = rl.destState /*carrier lane matches any contract lane*/
        JOIN 
    carrier c on c.id = l.companyId
        JOIN 
    user u ON u.id = l.masterId and u.type = 4 /* lane owner is a carrier */
WHERE
    r.expireDate >= NOW()
        AND r.open = '1'
        AND r.active = '1'
```

Comment: One note, a shipper could have many lanes as could a carrier, which makes simple JOIN's very intensive; so much so that the query actually times out after 30 seconds.

Comment: It would really help if you would show a SQL statement that attempts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT S.id, S.originState, S.destinationState
FROM carrier AS C, shipper AS S
WHERE (C.originState = S.originState
    OR C.originState = S.destinationState
    OR C.destinationState = S.originState
    OR C.destinationState = S.destinationState)
    AND C.id = 34
```

34 is the id of the carrier your are filtering on.

You could also do the same thing with a JOIN.

Comment: This would work really well except for that we are dealing with 2 different tables. There is a route table (for carriers) and a lane table (for shippers)

Comment: Both tables have both columns originState and destinationState?

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, it's pretty straightforward.  This assumes that the primary key of each table id `id` and that foreign key columns are of the form `table_id`.

Here's one way to get the result:

```
 SELECT c.*
   FROM carrier c
   JOIN route r
     ON r.carrier_id = c.id
   JOIN lane l
     ON l.originState = r.originState
    AND l.destinationState = r.destinationState
   JOIN contract o
     ON o.id = l.contract_id
   JOIN shipper s
     ON s.id = o.shipper_id
  GROUP BY c.id
```

- Each carrier has zero, one or more routes.
- Each route has a origin and destination state.
- Each shipper contract "lane" has an origin and destination state.
- A route will match a "lane" if the origin and destination states match.
- A "lane" references a single contract.
- A contract references a single shipper.

There's a potential for multiple matches, so we use a GROUP BY pk of the carrier table to return a unique list of carriers.

Comment: Thanks. This is more-or-less the multi join query I had. Nonetheless, the group by c.id did cut down the query time a bit. Still, we're at 20 seconds, which is too much time since this query is run multiple times (once for each contract). Was hoping there was an elegant way to say does one of this carriers routes exist in this shippers' list of lanes?